# Adding items to a generic list (novice)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, addition

I'm some what embarrassed to even ask this but I know there is a better way to do this I just don't know how

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(22);
numbers.Add(3);
numbers.Add(4);
numbers.Add(9);
numbers.Add(14);
numbers.Add(15);
//...
```

Comment: you dont really need to specify the size of the list up front. Just a side comment. Also, there is nothing like a stupid question I have seen professionals with lots of exp write code like this. Good Luck

Comment: perpetualcoder: regarding "code like this": I don't know of another way to fill a list unless it is a mathematical equation or instruction you can use. If you need to fill it with specific literals, there is no way around this (or the collection initializer, which is just a condensed form of a string of `ICollection.Add`s).

Comment: @Femaref: He asked for a better way, you provided an alternative syntax. "code like this" was not intended to criticize the code but to say that " its ok you can code like this ". Sorry if I came off as a smarta$$.

Comment: nah, it didn't seem smartass, but the expression seemed abit... odd at least. There is some code you simply can't write better and it still will be less than optimal, this includes this particular problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(22) { 3, 4, 9, ..., 99 };
```

shorter than that? Only if your numbers follow a pattern which could be expressed mathematically.

This is the [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: Except that the array should be inside the parenthesis, and the 22 should be removed.

Comment: No. the 22 is the initial capacity, and the curly braces are the collection initializer.

Comment: The 22 specifies an initial capacity, if you know how many elements you have, there is no reason not to add it. Remember, collection initializers work on types that implement ICollection, so they end up reducing to ICollection.Add() calls, you're still going to get a performance benefit by specifying the capacity. On another note, hey Ken...

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner. thanks that 1000% less ugly than what I had;

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(22)
{
    3, 4, 9,
    14, // ...
};
```

Comment: +1 For linking to the doc on object initializers; they're very useful, and not just for collections.

Comment: Please see my answer. Run your code and see if it works..cuz it's not for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of C# 3.0, at least, you can use an initializer, like so:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{ 3, 4, 9, ... , 99 };
```

(Specifying the initial capacity (22) isn't terribly necessary...)